# Sessions and cookies security and overhead

Tags: php

I have a log in system where a user can check the "Remember me" option. When the user checks that option, I store the session_id into a cookie and write his session_id, ip, browser info, etc into a database session table. So when the user comes back, I make sure the cookie has not been faked based on session_id/ip/browser/etc that is stored in the session table.

Now that seems like it might be a lot of overhead and db writing. Is there a better and secure way to do it without so much overhead?

Comment: i would never use ip to check identity. many people can share one ip, and one person can use multiple ips. Also, sounds like very little overhead to me.

Comment: It's not only an ip, bunch of other informations as well. What would you do instead then?

Comment: if its not a bank, just the session id would do fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a trade-off: when the data is not being stored in a database, it ends up hitting the server's local filesystem where PHP stores the session data. Phrased a different way: what is slower? One random access database hit or one random access disk hit?.

I find storing the session to the database to be a more elegant solution as it's easier to track users and their sessions than guessing based on file system contents. It also allows you to manually log off a user at any point or simulate logon sessions (one time password resets).

If you're using MySQL, set engine for the "session" table you're using to MEMORY and you'll always have an extremely fast lookup that shouldn't affect user experience.

Comment: So by server's local filesystem, you are saying you would store the information in a file on a server?

Comment: Yes, PHP's default session handler will create a file in a temporary directory to store the contents of that session. People tend to overlook that when obsessing over "simple" solutions.

Comment: Yes but I also need to save a cookie on the computer so when the user comes back it will automatically logs him in. This cookie also has to be secure.

Comment: That's a separate issue entirely: a cookie is just a small chunk of data that the user is *supposed* to hold onto. They are free to disregard it completely, delete it at random, use it repeatedly (even after it's expired), or even give it to others (legitimately or not) and there isn't anything you can do about it.

Comment: Well if I am designing a log in system with the option of the user being able to auto log in when they come back/reopen the browser, I want to make sure the cookie is not spoofed and it is the same user.